# Concatenate in FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extract the first 8 characters of a string while also inserting a "/" into the 8th character position using .FormulaR1C1. But, I don't think I have the concatenate function written quite right.

I need

```
MK442LLA-PB-3RC
```

to become

```
MK442LL/A
```

The R1C1 concatenate formula I used is as follows:

```
With Range("D2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(RC[-1], 7)""/""MID(RC[-1], 8, 1))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
End With
```

Note: I'm using Mid() instead of Right() because the initial numbers vary in length.

Comment: You're missing commas between your arguments in `CONCATENATE`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead of using '.FormulaR1C1'? Offset accordingly..

```
Sub concatFirstEight()

'last row
lastRow = range("D1048576").end(xlup).row

'set your range
Set concatRange = Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

'loop through range and add a "/" between the 7th and 8th character
For Each c In concatRange
    c.Value = Mid(c, 1, 7) & "/" & Mid(c, 8, 1)
Next

End Sub
```